# Change RelativeLayout from Java in Android

Tags: android

I have this XML RelativeLayout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeBackGround"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img1"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:src="@drawable/sample" />

        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"
            android:background="@drawable/bubble_left" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="text1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="text2"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm trying to to do is to change the gravity of the RelativeLayout from right to left based on the row like so

```
 wrapper = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.relativeBackGround);


 if (even) {

         wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);//this one isn't working
         //How can I change the alignment of linout to be on the left of the img1? 

  } else {

         wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);



 }
```

the setGravity isn't working, and I'm not sure how to do the alignment, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the layout of the LinearLayout with something similar to the following:

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linout);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
         RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Then just switch the rule based on whether it's odd or even row.